# Can you pass command line values to pyomo, like sys.argv for python scripts?

Tags: python, command-line, pyomo

In regular python scripts, you can pass command line parameters to python scripts with the `sys.argv`. For example, a python script named `parameter_pass.py` that contains:

```
# simple python example

import sys

val = sys.argv[1]

print(val)
```

Called with `python parameter_pass.py hi` prints 'hi' to the console. But the same does not work for a `pyomo solve` command line call as far as I can tell. Is there a way to pass command line parameters beyond solver options to a pyomo model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of an easy way to do this with the `pyomo solve` command line interface but you can easily do this by using the scripting interface to Pyomo. Just write a Python script that builds a concrete Pyomo model and calls a solver and you can run it using `python mymodel.py`. Then you can add anything else you want to the Python script including passing in command line values.